# How to make a mesh follow certain rules?

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, armature, physics

I am unable to understand a scenario where a whole turret is moving with an empty object. And it also follows physics rules.. Like if empty is moved along side z axis, mesh will move till a certain point.

Then after mesh won't move, won't deform, or won't loose it's shape. Also when turrets head is rotated it will rotate some parts of it automatically. It moves according to it's joints and moves other parts automatically as well. Even moving a single bone far from mesh won't strech the mesh.

A gif file will be able to clear the scenario in more detail and there is blender file link too. So help me understand how this is acheived and what's the name of this process.

[image: turret following realworld physics]

[Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15EHdvPEGvk7Vs66-qDyTHnjMcZmYu5N-/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: "Inverse kinematics" (or "IK") is probably a good search term to use if Googling this.

What do you desire to happen? Do you wish the feet to leave the ground when lifting the turret? Do you wish the legs to stretch like rubber bands when lifting the turret?

Comment: @amonroejj  This file is not mine. I don't want to do anything with this turret. I want to know how the auther of this file acheived this. Because the turret is made from metal and metal don't strech. So this is having perfect physics. If I can find how auther did this then I can use it in my next animation where human body won't strech and it won't deform. Body mesh will be in exact shape even if i accidentally move bone too far. So it will most useful in my next animation.

Comment: Oh yeah..... I got it....FK and IK is the correct answer for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the help of @amonroejj i found the solution. To achive this kind of scenario we have to set up FK and IK while connecting bones. And I was not aware that connecting two bones allows mesh not to deform and strech...